# Draw marker using locate in Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, javascript

I'm trying to use locate function from Leaflet in R, I'd like a marker to show up after clicking on locate button but the following code only centers and zooms the view on the user's geolocation. I'm new to JS, and I thought passing the `drawMarkers: true`, from [the manual](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol)  would map markers:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)
library(leaflet.extras)


punto = st_sfc(st_point(c(-96.951239, 19.4600523))) %>% st_set_crs(4326)
punto_b = punto %>% st_transform(32614) %>% st_buffer(50000) %>% st_transform(4326)  %>% st_as_sf

leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = "https://gitlab.com/datamarindo/anps/-/raw/master/logo_prona.png",
  iconWidth = 100, iconHeight = 100)
  

l <- leaflet(data = punto) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(dat = punto, icon = leafIcons) %>%
      addPolygons(data = punto_b, fillColor = "yellow", weight = 4) %>% 
      addMeasure() %>% 
      addMiniMap() %>% 
      addEasyButton(easyButton(
         icon="fa-crosshairs", title="Locate Me",
         onClick=JS("function(btn, map){ map.locate({setView: true, drawMarker: true});}")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to do using direct Javascript; besides that, the html that `leaflet` in R produces is heavy and has some binaries that make it really difficult to read, html in JS is as plain as this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pronatura Ver 50 km</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script language="javascript">
      var map;

      function init() {
         map = new L.Map('map');
         L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            maxZoom: 18
         }).addTo(map);

         // map view before we get the location
         map.setView(new L.LatLng(19.460052, -96.951239), 8);
         L.circle([19.460052, -96.951239], {
                color: 'moccasin',
                fillColor: 'orange',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                radius: 50000
             }).addTo(map);
        var greenIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://gitlab.com/datamarindo/anps/-/raw/master/logo_prona.png',
            iconSize:     [90, 95], // size of the icon
            iconAnchor:   [45, 45], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        });
        L.marker([19.460052, -96.951239], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
      }

      function onLocationFound(e) {
         var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
         var location = e.latlng
         L.marker(location).addTo(map)
         L.circle(location, radius).addTo(map);
      }

      function onLocationError(e) {
         alert(e.message);
      }

      function getLocationLeaflet() {
         map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
         map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

         map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
      }
   </script>

</head>
<body onLoad="javascript:init();">
   <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>
   <input type="button" value="Mostrar mi ubicación!" onClick="javascript:getLocationLeaflet();">
   
</body>
</html>
```